# Exclude all generated code from dartanalyzer

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code, static-analysis

I am trying to exclude all generated files from a package using the following `analysis_options.yaml` file.

```yaml
include: package:pedantic/analysis_options.yaml
analyzer:
    strong-mode:
        implicit-casts: false
        implicit-dynamic: false
    exclude:
        - lib/**.g.dart
```

I still get errors for a file called `lib/store/state/presentations_state.g.dart` breaking the rule `implicit_dynamic_parameter`. If I exlcude `**.g.dart` without the `lib/` prefix, `dartanalyzer` works properly, but the `dart-code.dart-code` VS Code plugin reports `Undefined alias. dart(parse_error)` somewhere in the first line of the YAML file, leaving the whole project marked as having an error.

I could reproduce this in both monorepos having multiple packages and single packages as well.

Comment: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/25551

Comment: Wow, I got pretty angry reading that there are issues open for 4 years now with this. What is worse is that writing `- "**.g.dart"`, `- lib/**.g.dart` and `- **.g.dart` all end up with different errors and lints, so it seems to be dependent on the rule how they exclude files.

Answer (score 30):

I put the following to the `analysis_options.yaml` which worked for me:

```yaml
analyzer:
  exclude:
    - '**.freezed.dart'
    - '**.g.dart'
    - '**.gr.dart'
    - '**/generated_plugin_registrant.dart'
```

All files matching the patterns are no longer analysed, independent of its location in the file path.

The quotation marks are necessary to prevent syntax errors in the yaml

Comment: @jakub-s why did you edit the answer? And why did use double quotation marks?

Comment: added another generated type, double quotation was by mistake

Answer (score 1):

See https://github.com/dart-lang/source_gen/tree/master/source_gen#configuring-combining_builder-ignore_for_file

Assuming the generator you use is based on `package:source_gen` you can use this trick to create the right ignores in the generated file!

https://github.com/kevmoo/peanut.dart/commit/9877105daecf59b8f5eb25431ac691a38a3e636c
https://github.com/kevmoo/stats/commit/bb2fefaa22fc11c10acfe2f6418b3abba1e51909
https://github.com/kevmoo/build_cli/commit/619495c91caab873c2f48ac36a941c893d9b86b7

Comment: Thanks. I will check how to `ignore_for_file` the `implicit-dynamic: false` analysis option.

Comment: If you copy the warning in your IDE or run analyzer from the command line you will see the "code name" for the warning – that's what you ignore!

Comment: In this case, there are many:

implicit_dynamic_parameter
implicit_dynamic_variable
implicit_dynamic_type
implicit_dynamic_function

and likely others...